# Why is moon light cold?

Tags: visible-light

Why is light from the moon cold? For example full moon light shining on a surface or material will cause it to be colder than a surface or object nearby that is shaded from the moonlight. What causes this phenomenon?

[image: Moon light test]

Comment: This question and the experiment are based on a false premise.

Comment: Could you explain more?

Comment: First of all, light cannot be cold or hot. Temperature is a thermodynamic state that is applicable to matter. Light is not matter.

Comment: @DavidHammen What false premise?  The OP presents data and asks for an explanation.

Comment: The false premise is that moonlight is cold. Try your experiment on a clear night with no moon in the sky. Whatever you are using to shield the glass of water from moonlight is also shielding it from the clear sky.

Comment: @DavidHammen  I think it is the opposite , though I have a +1 to your comment.  I think blocking moonlight reflects back the black body radiation of the water, keeping it warmer.

Comment: @annav - That's exactly what I was saying. Whether or not the Moon is present is irrelevant. What is relevant is the equivalent temperature of the object above the glass of water. In one case it's the clear night sky, about 20 kelvins lower than the surrounds, in the other its an object at ambient that blocks the path to the clear night sky.

Comment: @garyp I agree. It's a good experiment. You don't need any premise to do an experiment. You could conduct an experiment on the relationship between jumping up and down and rainbows. I believe issue was taken with "words used in the conclusion/interpretation" of the data

Comment: @DavidHammen    How can the conclusion be the false premise? Given that the only variable changing is whether one is getting moonlight or not, and given the fact that the one receiving moonlight is colder than the one who is not, we can conclude that moonlight cools. Now the wrong premise would be: "Given that the only variable changing is whether one is getting moonlight or not"  That might be the false premise.

Comment: @DiegoOrellana The OP did not check the null hypothesis, which is that it is something other than moonlight. The way to test this is to use the same setup but on a clear, moonless night. It is the thermal radiation to the sky that makes the glass cool, not moonlight.

Answer (score 10):

Probably the heat radiation from the object that you blocked the moonlight with is the cause. Also if the blocking object was close then you not only blocked the moonlight but also part of the sky, which has a very low radiation temperature. You can cool the object or use an object with very low emissivity in the infrared. I am assuming that all other radiation/heat sources, such as humans, had exactly constant impact in the experiment.

Comment: The thermal temperature of the clear sky isn't that cold. It's a lot closer to 273 kelvin than 2.73 kelvin (CMBR temperature). But yes, this is the answer to the question.

Answer (score 8):

As my2cts said, it may be attributable to the way you blocked the moonlight. In image this is:

[image]

If excessive blocking area is used then you are not only blocking radiation from the moon but also radiation coming out from the water into the dark sky, thus preventing water to cool.

Try, if possible, to repeat the experiment making sure to use a "proper blocking area" and tell us the results. Or tell us if you have already used a "proper blocking area" to look for other explanation.

Answer (score 2):

In thermal infrared, the moon is partly obscured by the atmosphere. The atmosphere has a bit of a window from about 8 micrometer to about 13 micrometer, the region of thermal infrared that your Fluke is probably sensitive to.

However, there is absorption by ozone centered at $9.6\ \mu$m, which will affect the image to obscure the Moon. The emission at these wavelengths will brighten the background.